# Loan on my inherited property

Tags: loans, home-loan

My father died in 2009 and left me all his property and belongings in a will. I have lived in the home and paid the taxes since then. Is it possible to get a loan against the property so I can fix the home and also pay for the probate court with a will?

Answer (score 6):

A bank isn't going to offer to lend you money on a property you don't own.

You first need to finish the process of probate and get a clear title.

Then it's your house and a bank with lend you money based on a combination of your income and the home's value.